# TypeError: ctx[3] is undefined in Svelte Astro app

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, astrojs

Completely lost as why this is breaking. I'm working on an autocomplete kinda component that was working perfectly with an array of strings. But I'm converting it to use a array of objects with keys `slug` and `name` and now I'm getting a type error that I've never seen before.

```
  {#if filteredPlants.length > 0}
    <hr class="mx-4"/>
    <ul class="mx-4 my-4">
      {#each filteredPlants as plant, index}
        <li
          class={`py-1 rounded-lg ${hiLitedPlant.name === plant.name ? 'bg-black text-white' : ''}`}
          on:mouseenter={() => hiLiteIndex = index}
          on:click={() => navigate(hiLitedPlant.slug)}
          on:keydown={navigateList}
        >
          <p class="mx-2">{plant.name}</p>
        </li>
      {/each}           
    </ul>
  {/if}
```

the filtering is working properly. if I console log it outputs the expected values but upon having `filteredPlants.length > 0` it starts throwing a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ctx[3] is undefined`. If I remove the index variable from the loop it becomes ctx[2] if that helps. I am using typescript so if it is a typing issue I don't know why it's even compiling

Answer (score 0):

The error came from inside the tailwind class. Accessing hiLitedPlant.name threw the error because at first render it was undefined until the user was able to interact

```
let hiLiteIndex: number = -1;
$: hiLitedPlant = filteredPlants[hiLiteIndex] ?? { name: '', slug: ''};
```

```
on:click={() => navigate(plant.slug)}
```

this fixed it